# C++0x lambda return value type-inferencing rules

Tags: lambda, c++11, type-inference

Consider the two lambda functions in the following VC++ 10.0 code:

```
template <typename T>
void eq(uint fieldno, T value) {
    table* index_table = db.get_index_table(fieldno);
    if (index_table == nullptr) return;
    std::set<uint> recs;
    index_table->scan_index<T>(value, [&](uint recno, T n)->bool {
        if (n != value) return false;
        recs.insert(recno);
        return true;
    });
    add_scalar_hits(fieldno, recs).is_hit =
        [=](tools::wsdb::field_instance_t& inst) {
            return boost::get<T>(inst) == value;
        };
}
```

In the first lambda function, I was forced to use the `->bool` return type specification whereas in the second lambda the compiler was perfectly happy to infer the return type.

My question is: when can the compiler infer the return type on a lambda? Is it only when you have a simple one-liner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Is it only when you have a simple one-liner?"

Yes. According to the latest public C++0x draft (§5.1.2/4),

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is as if the *trailing-return-type* denotes the following type:
>
> - if the *compound-statement* is of the form
>
>   `{ return` *attribute-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*  *expression* `; }`
>
>   the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conver- sion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - **otherwise, `void`.**
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>  auto x1 = [](int i){ return i; }; // OK: return type is int
>  auto x2 = []{ return { 1, 2 }; }; // error: the return type is void (a
>                                    // braced-init-list is not an expression)
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Therefore, your first lambda expression is interpreted as returning `void`, which is not right, so you need to add a `-> bool` to explicitly specify the return type.