# Are lambdas supposed to be able to see local classes?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, lambda, visual-studio-2012

The following gives the error `'one': identifier not found` in VS2010 and VS2012

```
int main()
{
    struct one {};
    [](){ return one(); }();
}
```

And with a slight tweak...

```
int main()
{
    struct one {};
    [](){ one uno; return uno; }();
}
```

VS2010/VS2012 both have a compiler crash from this code.

So, the question is (ignoring the compiler crash), are lambas supposed to be able to have visibility of local classes?

Comment: Doesn't the second one need an explicit return type for the lambda? Not that this is an excuse for the compiler crashing.

Comment: @SteveJessop _need_? I don't know the explicit return rules for lambdas - but there's only 1 return and it's type is well known. Why do you _need_ it?

Comment: @Dave: Technically, you need an explicit return type if the function body contains anything more than a single return statement. That seems rather odd to me, but it's what the language spec says.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4097876/1171191

Comment: @MikeSeymour DR975 is proposed to remove that restriction, but the details are a bit tricky.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138939/return-type-deduction

Comment: Maybe not exact duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122282/are-function-local-typedefs-visible-inside-c0x-lambdas According to my bug reports this was fixed but apparently not!

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774170/c-using-a-local-class-in-a-lambda-causes-a-compiler-crash

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774172/template-argument-deduction-always-deduces-to-int-in-a-lambda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, VS is incorrect.  From 5.1.2p7:

> [...] for purposes of name lookup, [...] the *compound-statement* is considered in the context of the *lambda-expression*.